# java.io.IOException: Un-terminated quoted field at end of CSV line

Tags: android, parsing, csv

I have a CSV file(written in german language) and I m parsing it in my code.

```
CSVParser newLineParser = new CSVParser('\n');

        try {

            String[] points = newLineParser.parseLine(csv);
            CSVParser commaParser = new CSVParser();
            int pointsLength = points.length;

            for (int i = 1; i < pointsLength; i++) {

                String[] pointComponents = commaParser.parseLine(points[i]);
            }

        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
        }
```

I am getting error in the parseLine method as:

```
java.io.IOException: Un-terminated quoted field at end of CSV line
```

what may be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 1):

What I get from this is that in your CSV file a quote is opened but isn't closed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OpenCSV API then this could be the problem:

Issue: One or more value in the csv file have multiple lines.

Fix: Use commaParser.parseLineMulti(points[i]) instead.

```
Source: Http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVParser.html#parseLineMulti(java.lang.String)
```

Answer (score -1):

malformed csv file

do some printouts in your loop, to see what happens before the program blows up.